# OSI Approved ライセンスについて

Tags: python, ライセンス

pip-licenses --from-classifierでライセンス一覧を表示したところ、
feedparserパッケージがOSI Approved ライセンスと表示されていました。

feedparser            5.2.1      OSI Approved

このパッケージをインポートで参照しているアプリをMITライセンスで配布しても大丈夫でしょうか。
配布する際はこのライセンスを表記する必要があるのでしょうか。

ネットで調べても有力な情報が見つからずに困っております。
どなたかご存知の方はいらっしゃらないでしょうか。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

※ 注意: 私は法律の専門家ではないので、この回答の厳密な正確性は保証できません。内容は必ずご自身でも確認するようにしてください。

---

まず OSI-approved License とは Open Source Initiative (OSI) という団体によって承認されたライセンスの集合を示す言葉であり、特定のライセンスひとつを指しているものではありません ([参考1](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Open_Source_Initiative#%E3%83%A9%E3%82%A4%E3%82%BB%E3%83%B3%E3%82%B9%E3%83%AC%E3%83%93%E3%83%A5%E3%83%BC)、[2](https://ja.osdn.net/projects/opensource/wiki/licenses)、[3](https://opensource.org/licenses))。

さて、では feedparser はどのようなライセンスを持っているのでしょうか？　pip が表示する情報だけだと分からないので、[feedparser のソースコード・リポジトリ](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser)を見てみます。LICENSE というファイルに詳しいライセンス情報が書かれています。2018 年 9 月現在、このライセンスは何か名前のついた有名なライセンスではなく、特に以下のように書かれています。

> - Redistributions in binary form must reproduce the above copyright notice,
>     this list of conditions and the following disclaimer in the documentation
>     and/or other materials provided with the distribution.

したがって、バイナリとして配布する限りは、LICENSE ファイルの内容を併記する形にすれば大丈夫そうです。ただし正確なところは著作者に対して確認が必要かもしれません。

なお feedparser のライセンスが "OSI Approved" と表示されているのは [`setup.py` にそう書いてある](https://github.com/kurtmckee/feedparser/blob/2b11c8028321ed43cbaf313f83b0c94820143d66/setup.py#L21)からだと思われますが、OSI が公開している[承認済みライセンス一覧](https://opensource.org/licenses/alphabetical)には feedparser のライセンスが載っていないように見えます。このあたり正確なことは問い合わせが必要かもしれません。

Comment: 英語読むのが苦手なんですよ。英語が読めないとリファレンスとかを読むとき本当に不便で困ってます。google翻訳してみたら再配布する際は配布物と一緒に著作権表記を複製してくださいまでは読めたんですけどその著作権表記というのがLICENSE ファイルの内容のことなのですね。ライセンスはいろいろ種類があってややこしくて怖いのでgithab等に載せようとなるとビクビクします。

Comment: @user30138 さん、feedparser に限らず多くのオープンソースソフトウェアでは一番上に置いてある LICENSE という名前のファイルや COPYRIGHT という名前のファイルに著作権情報が書かれていることが多いです。参考までに ;)

Comment: GitHabでfeedparser language:Python license:mitで検索してライセンス表記を調べているのですが(16件該当)、どのリポジトリにもfeedparserのLICENSE ファイルの内容を併記した形跡はありません。これらのファイルはライセンスを使用するという点でアウトということになるのでしょうか。

Comment: @user30138 さん、確かに16件見つかりますが、単に feedparser に言及しているだけで依存していないものもあるようです。また、依存していてもリポジトリで feedparser を再配布することはしていないものもありました。16件全ては見ていませんしバイナリとして配布されるときにどうなっているのかの確認もしていませんが、ライセンスとは別に著作者の許可を得た可能性もあるので、私からは何とも言えません。

Comment: @nekketsuuuさん、依存というのはPythonソース内でimport feedparser でfeedparserを使用していること、再配布というのはfeedparserソースそのものをリポジトリに入れているという理解でよいでしょうか。依存していてもfeedparserそのもののソースを入れなければライセンス表記は不要なのでしょうか。また確認になりますが、GitHabにリボジトリを登録することはバイナリとして配布するということになるのでしょうか、あるいはそのアプリを自宅やWeb上のサーバーで稼働させるということが配布ということなのでしょうか。

Comment: @user30138 さん、あまり細かいことにコメントで答えてしまうと正確性が気になるので、別途ご質問頂けますでしょうか？　ライセンスに書かれていること以上の判断は、言葉の解釈問題になってしまうので……。あるいはたとえば「ライセンス　配布」で検索したら出てくる[ソフトの配布とライセンス (可知 豊)](https://www.catch.jp/openoffice/lisence/softbank_cmag200408.html)などの記事が参考になるかもしれません。